# Is there a way to preserve the original filename in strapi.io's file-upload?

Tags: strapi

If I use the file-upload in strapi.io, the filenames become a random name. Is there a way to preserve the original file name (eventually with random suffix) (e.g. for SEO)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not at the moment without custom modification (extensions) to the upload plugin. The current system was put in place to ensure there was absolutely zero possibility of a file name conflict (Say two people upload a file called `file01.img`). A hash is created to make sure that one does not overwrite the other.

Comment: Thanks. I will make a new strapi-provider-upload-* with something like: `const originalFilename = file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");` and `/uploads/${originalFilename}_${file.hash}${file.ext}` to get unique filenames with describing words in filename.